# How to check if a character at a certian index matches an item within an array

Tags: java

I'm trying to take a string as an input (around 5 - 7 characters), iterate through each character and check whether or not it matches a character from an array. For example:

```
static String Registration(String reg) {
    int[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9,};
    if (reg.length() >= 7) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reg.length(); i++) {
            reg.indexOf(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The above is clearly wrong. However, I hope it illustrates what I'm trying to do. For example, if the string was "H3llo", I would want to check each character in the string and see if it matches with any items in the array. If it does, I would like to store the index as an int.

This is probably not an efficient way of doing it, but it's the only way I can think of with my current level of learning.

Comment: What do you mean with "whether or not it matches a character from an array"? Your array is an array of integers and not characters. Are you trying to see if the String contains a number 0-9?

Comment: What exactly is the array of characters you want to check, as @OHGODSPIDERS asked, it makes a difference if you just wanna check the presence of integers in your string or any other certain characters.

Comment: Be aware that what you are trying to do is something that `Regular Expressions` has standardized

Comment: @ControlAltDel, I think @ItchyPrune just wants to use some basic iteration and comparison operators instead of `regex`.

Comment: @ShivangGupta I agree with you. However I am a RegEx "evangelist" - I want the world to learn about the "glory" of what text search can be! Not that I expect that everyone in practical life will use them - I just want people to be aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several problems with your code here:

- your `numbers` array is of type int, however you want to compare the characters. use char[] instead and use chars in your array instead of ints like this: `'0', '1', ...`
- indexOf is not a existing method for arrays, instead use a for loop to iterate through all the entries of the array and compare them by hand
- your function claims to return a String `public String Registration` but you want to return an int. change this to `public int Registration`.
- You have no return in your function. you have to use the keyword `return` in your function if your function should return something.

A possible solution may look like this:

```
public static int Registration(String reg) {
  char[] numbers = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7' , '8', '9',}; // use a char array char[] and add numbers as chars to array.
  if (reg.length() >= 7) {
    for (int i = 0; i < reg.length(); i++) {
      char character = reg.charAt(i);
      for(char number : numbers)
      {
        if(number == character)
        {
          return i; // found a matching character, return the index of the matching character
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // return -1 for the case that we find nothing.
  return -1;
}
```

please try to understand what happens here and do not just copy and paste the solution.

Note: the thing you wish to do can be easily implemented with RegEx, however, this may be too hard for you at your current stage.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed response. The nested for each loop is exactly what i was looking for. Yes, i'm not up to Regex in my learning yet but will be sure to keep it in mind. Thanks again!